# The usage of quotation marks

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotation-marks, periods, colons

I'm discussing and comparing two books and I want to know if I'm using quotation marks correctly:

> Both books are known for being existential and the reader is bombarded with questions throughout the books. ‘Whose fault is this? Who did this? Why did it happen this way? Did it even happen this way?’

I'm having **a lot** of doubts over the punctuation in this small piece of text:

- Should there be a colon after *throughout the books*?
- Should there be individual quotation marks for every question, or is this right?
- If every question must have individual quotation marks, how would you correctly separate the questions? Using dots after the right quotation mark? Using commas?

EDIT: I must write the final version using a pen and paper.

Comment: Punctuation rules are dictated by style manuals. My suggestion is to add the colon you suggest and skip the quotation marks for the questions: Put them all in _italics_. Separate all the questions by giving them a "?" plus a space: _Whose fault is this? Who did this? Why did it happen this way? Did it even happen this way?_ There are other ways of doing this, of course. This isn't the only way, just my preference as a technical editor.

Comment: @BillFranke My main problem with that approach is that I have to *write* the text using a pen and paper.

Comment: In that case, you can underline each question and question mark or else put each question in quotation marks, whichever is easier for you. There are no hard and fast rules about what way to do it is best. Whatever works best for you **and** the reader is best.

Comment: "Both books are known for being existential and the reader is bombarded with questions throughout the books: Whose fault is this, Who did this, Why did it happen this way, Did it even happen this way, ..." -- one way is to use a colon and **not** use quotes. That reads better.  -->

Comment: -> The questions themselves are not literally important -- the fact that the author raises the kind of questions is what matters. In fact, the questions may not even be exact copy-paste from the source in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no absolute need for a colon, and if the questions are separate questions, then putting each in its own quotation marks will make this clear. I suggest, therefore:

> Both books are known for being existential, and the reader is bombarded
>   with questions throughout the books. ‘Whose fault is this?’ Who did
>   this?’ ‘Why did it happen this way?’ ‘Did it even happen this way?’

Comment: Yes; and this mimics a bombardment of questions.

Comment: However, the intention here is not so much as to quote the author as to convey the idea of existentialism in the work.

Comment: Barrie, see if the edits are not what you meant.

Comment: @Noah. Thanks. The first, but not the second. _This_ refers to 'putting each in its own quotation marks'.

Answer (score 0):

Both the original example, and all of the suggestions you give are each valid.

If using separate quotes, you could just leave that, use commas between the quotes, or place each on a separate line as a list (this latter only really if you used a colon).

It would also be valid to italicise the questions, rather than using quotation marks.

A style guide might restrict your options though.

Answer (score 0):

I find the sentence structure problematic beyond the questions of punctuation that you pose: it is not completely clear whether you intend the books' existentialism to be demonstrated by the questions, and either way the 'and' is inappropriate or, at best, awkward.

I would dispense with the quotation marks entirely - the questions don't come across as literal quotes - and, as you suggest, use a colon.

Please excuse the near rewrite, but how about:

> Both books are known for their existentialism. They bombard the reader
>   with questions: Whose fault is this? Who did this? Why did it happen
>   this way? Did it even happen this way?